# Variable as command

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to set a variable with the terminal name and use that variable to open the terminal in fullscreen. It would be something like:

```
if [ "$DESKTOP" = "gnome" ]; then
    if command_exists gnome-terminal; then
        terminal=$(gnome-terminal)
    fi
elif [ "$DESKTOP" = "mate" ]; then
    if command_exists mate-terminal; then
        terminal=$(mate-terminal)
    fi
fi
$terminal --working-directory="$HOME/code/" --window --full-screen &
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: and the question is ?

Comment: The thing is the code I've put there doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply replace `$( )` by nothing.

```
if [ "$DESKTOP" = "gnome" ]; then
    if command_exists gnome-terminal; then
        terminal=gnome-terminal
    fi
elif [ "$DESKTOP" = "mate" ]; then
    if command_exists mate-terminal; then
        terminal=mate-terminal
    fi
fi
$terminal --working-directory="$HOME/code/" --window --full-screen &
```

`$( )` is use to run a command and paste output, either in a variable or in command line.

above code may not run, if either foo terminal is undefined, I would suggest

```
noterminal=true
if [ "$DESKTOP" = "gnome" ]; then
    if command_exists gnome-terminal; then
        gnome-terminal --working-directory="$HOME/code/" --window --full-screen &
        noterminal=false
    fi
elif [ "$DESKTOP" = "mate" ]; then
    if command_exists mate-terminal; then
        mate-terminal --working-directory="$HOME/code/" --window --full-screen &
        noterminal=false
    fi
fi
if $noterminal
then
   echo unable to find terminal 
   ## or other GUI alert system.
   ## or xterm as per mmmint sugestion
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know `xterm` is available on most Linux-based OS.

In any case the used terminal will be found in the `$TERM` variable.

Comment: I don't think that's what the question was about